# Two assets with the same mean and standard deviation - Would there be any benefit?

Tags: portfolio-management, asset-allocation

If I have two assets in a portfolio with the same standard deviation and mean and the correlation between the assets is 0, theoretically could there be a situation where it would be beneficial to having a portfolio like this?

Answer (score 2):

It will bring diversification benefits to your portfolio. 
Mean and standard deviation alone only measures the first two moments of the individual asset returns, with no regards for their joint distribution and correlation structure.

Assuming the mean and volatility measurements are the same for $2$ assets with correlation $corr<1$, then combining them will improve your portfolio's Sharpe ratio. To extend it further, assuming you have $n$ assets with same mean and volatility, then combining them into a portfolio will generally be beneficial if their average correlation is less than one.

In fact, if you run a numerical optimization for these portfolio using Sharpe maximum as the objective metric, the resultant weighting scheme will favor those assets with low or negative correlation automatically.